# Proving that $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ is the splitting field for $f(x)=x^4 - x^2 + 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials, normal-extension

I have been given that $\omega = e^{\pi i\over{6}}$, a 12th root of unity. I have shown that $\omega$ is a root of the polynomial $f(t)=t^4 -t^2 +1$, as are $\omega^5,\omega^7,\omega^{11}$ and that $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Now I must show that $$\Gamma(\mathbb{Q(\omega):Q})$$ has order 4 (and subsequently that it is isomorphic to the Klein 4-group). My immediate thought is to show that $\mathbb{Q(\omega)}$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and hence $\mathbb{Q(\omega):Q}$ is a normal extension then use the fundamental theorem of Galois Theory, but I am unsure how to prove this. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Why are the other roots in $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$?

Comment: Hint: By writing $x = t^2$ write the entire extension as 2 quadratic extensions.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is it because they form a basis for $\mathbb{Q(\omega)}$? I thought it could be that but I was unsure. My other thought is, are they all Galois conjugates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ is a field, i.e. closed under multiplication, then  $\omega^5,\omega^7,\omega^{11}\in\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ and hence the splitting field of $f$: $$\mathbb{Q}(\omega,\omega^5,\omega^7,\omega^{11})=\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$$

Comment: Correct :-) ${}$